# Visual Studio 2008, Vista x64 and Kaspersky = blue screens (BSOD)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, bsod

We just got cool new workstations - 8 GB, 24 inches screens, Vista x64 and a lot of power -- I just love it !

But we are facing some really annoying problems : BSODs ! We found out that the instant you install Kaspersky MP4 on a workstation, you can get BSOD while debugging ASPX pages. You can get one BSOD in a week or three in an hour...

Those who :

1. Don't have Kaspersky
2. Don't debug ASPX pages
3. Don't work...

do not got BSOD.

Note : We use usually use IE8 but it also have happened in Firefox.

Now, the problem is : with all those BSOD, our IT department is on the way to replace  Vista x64 with XP 32... Bye bye RAM ! I do not want that, of course, so if anyone have a hint...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Kaspersky knows about the issue, but they don't have a fix yet. Please see the article in the [Kaspersky support site](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208279784).

Comment: It may apply... I will send them some memory dump :). By the way, we never add any problem with virus in 10 years but a lot with anti-virus :) Thanks for your answer nithins.